# Lua objects not unique

Tags: inheritance, lua, lua-table

While trying to create a very simple class inheritance, all objects seem to be sharing the same values

This is a simplification of my code :

```
--Generic class
Object = {}

function Object:new (type,id,name)
  o = {}
  self.type = type or "none"
  self.id = id or 0
  self.name = name or "noname"
  self.direction = "down"
  self.animations = {}
  self.animations.stack = {}
  self.animations.idle = {}
  self.animations.idle[self.direction] = {}
  setmetatable(o, self)
  self.__index = self
  return o
end

function Object:draw(x,y)
  local img = self.animations.idle["down"][0]
  print("drawing " ..self.name.." as "..img)
end

function Object:setimg(img)
  self.animations.idle["down"][0] = img
end

Player = Object:new()

-- Player class
function Player:new(id,name)
  local o = self

  o.id = id or 0
  o.name = name or "noname"

  o.collision = {}
  o.collision.type = "player"

  return o
end

function Player:move(x,y)
  print("moving to ",x,y)
end

-- Testing
blockimg = "block.png"
grassimg = "grass.png"
plyrimg = "player.png"

block = Object:new("solid",1,"block")
block:setimg(blockimg)

grass = Object:new("floor",3,"grass")
grass:setimg(grassimg)

player = Player:new(1, "plyr1")
player:setimg(plyrimg)

block:draw() -- >drawing grass as player.png
grass:draw() -- >drawing grass as player.png
player:draw()-- >drawing plyr1 as player.png
```

Since player:setimg was the last called, all "objects" ended up with the plyrimg, so they are not unique

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This function is creating, or overwriting, properties on the shared Object table each time a new Object instance is created.

```
function Object:new (type,id,name)
  o = {}
  self.type = type or "none"
  self.id = id or 0
  self.name = name or "noname"
  self.direction = "down"
  self.animations = {}
  self.animations.stack = {}
  self.animations.idle = {}
  self.animations.idle[self.direction] = {}
  setmetatable(o, self)
  self.__index = self
  return o
end
```

You need to create those properties on each new instance, if you want them to be unique. Otherwise, `Object:setimg` will look up the index chain to find `animations`, and place the image in the shared property.

```
function Object:new (type,id,name)
  local o = {}
  -- ...
  o.animations = {} -- Or in Player:new
  -- ...
  self.__index = self
  return setmetatable(o, self)
end
```

Comment: Damn I really didn't understand, so is pointless to initiate tables in the constructor?

Comment: It's not pointless! You just need to pay attention to _which_ table you are assigning to in the 'constructor' - remembering that  in `new`, `self` references the _class_ not the _instance_, when called as `Player:new` or `Object:new`.

Comment: AAAAAAAAAAAAHHHHHHHHHH I seeee, now I understand thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can avoid a lot of problems if you simply don't pass a self to the constructor. I usually define classes like this:

```
local class={x=0,y=0}
local _class={__index=Class}
-- I like prefixing metatables with _, but that's just a personal thing
class.new(x, y)
  return setmetatable({x=x, y=y}, _class)
end
class:print() print(self.x, self.y) end
class.sub(sub) return getmetatable(sub)==_class end
```

This is assuming the class is either in its own file or in a `do` block to keep the local variables hidden to anything but the class and its closures.

You can read more on this in the lua documentation here on github.